# Preloading JSON in Core Data with Swift4 and several relationships

Tags: ios, swift, xcode, core-data, entity-relationship

Who can help me with the code?

I need to import/preload my JSON
My Data Model has three entities and relationships to each other

Like Items and categories

I want to import all my items and give them a cateorie if the app is launching first time.

But if I do it like this, cat01 will be insert several times if I use it at other items, too. I want to insert 500 items and set a relationship to only 5 categories - how can I do that? And some times one item has two categories?

Thanks for help.

```
"entity1":
[{
            "name": "Item1",
            "info": "Loremipsum",
            "categorie": {
                "cat": "cat01"
            },
            "entity2": [{
                    "name": "ItemWithRelationship",
                    "info": "LoremipsumDolor"
            }]
}]




//Preload - Relationships 2
    fileprivate func preloadWithRelationshipsDECODE() {
        guard let preloadFileURL = Bundle.main.url(forResource: "preload_DB", withExtension: "json") else {
            return
        }

        guard let data = try? Data(contentsOf: preloadFileURL) else {
            return
        }

        do {

            //mit Array MIT Relationship
            let results = try JSONDecoder().decode(Raum.self, from: data)
            print(results.raum.count)

            for result in results.entity1{

                //Raum-DB
                let entityRaum: String = String(describing: Raumliste.self)
                let room = NSEntityDescription.insertNewObject(forEntityName: entityRaum, into: self.managedContext) as! Raumliste

                room.name = result.name
                room.info = result.info


                //Categorie
                let entityCat: String = String(describing: categorie.self)
                let cat = NSEntityDescription.insertNewObject(forEntityName: entityCat, into: self.managedContext) as! Categorie

                cat.name = result.categorie?.cat
                myCat.categorie_rls  = cat

                myCat.categorie_rls?.name = result.categorie?.cat


                for task in result.entity2!{
                    //Entitiy2-DB
                    let entityNR2: String = String(describing: MyEntity.self)
                    let extra = NSEntityDescription.insertNewObject(forEntityName: entityNR2, into: self.managedContext) as! MyEntity

                    extra.name = task.name!
                    room.addToExtraListe_rls(extra)

                    extra.info = task.info!

                    room.addToExtraListe_rls(extra)


                    saveContext()
                }


                do {
                    try managedContext.save()
                    print("gespeichert")

                } catch {
                    print("Error saving todo: \(error)")
                    print ("No value associated with key someKey (\"actual_key_if_you_defined_your_own\").")
                }
            }



        } catch let error as NSError {
            print("Fehler: \(error.localizedDescription)")
        }
    }
```

Comment: take a look @ https://www.appcoda.com/core-data-preload-sqlite-database/

Comment: Hmmm but this tutorial does not handle any relationship - do you mean the preloading only? That is not my problem... The question is how can I set relations more than one time to a "categorie" without insert it any time in the DB - I think it will be many to many, or?

Comment: JSON you provided does not make much sense, how is category associated with Entity? Tell us description of them or post the Schema image so that we can tell you which relationship model to use

Comment: Keep your created categories in a dictionary with name as key and if category with  name already exists in dictionary then don't insert a new object and instead assign  the existing category instance to the room object